# ValueError when selecting raster files that overlap an AOI using GeoPandas

Tags: raster, geopandas, overlapping-features, geodataframe, valueerror

I want to select only the raster files that overlap or intersect my AOI. I have a list of 900 raster files, and I calculate their footprints. Besides, I have my AOI.

Both, the footprints and the AOI are GeoDataFrames. I have troubles constructing my if statement. How can I check if two GeoDataFrames intersect with GeoPandas?

```py
intersect_footprints = []

AOI = load_vector("AOI.geojson")
footprint = import_files("footprints.geojson")

if footprint["geometry"].intersects(AOI["geometry"]):
    intersected_raster.append(files_path)
```

I have an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: files_path is the path of the raster file. I want to save in the list only the paths of the rasters that intersect my AOI

Answer (score 1):

Use the [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html#Inner-join):

```
import geopandas as gpd

extents = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\temp\extents.shp")
aoi = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\aoi.shp")
intersecting = gpd.sjoin(left_df=extents, right_df=aoi, how="inner")
intersecting.to_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\extents_intersecting_aoi.shp")
```

[image]